# Cant see my website

Tags: google-chrome, web

I think I can't see if my website is online. Chrome returns this error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

And some friends are telling me that they see it up. But I enter from my mobile with 4G and it is still down, what's going on?

Comment: It's definitely the fribo-mulator, [google it](http://www.google.com/?#q=%22fribo-mulator%22) for more fribo-mulator related problems

Comment: guys what's that? it's a joke or what? I googled it but no results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, what's the address?

Second, you should try clearing your cache, like so:

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?hl=en

Comment: "PussyDicks" is indeed online. Are you on a mac, pc, or other?

Comment: PC on ubuntu. I also checked with my iphone as I said and its looking down.

Comment: Okay. Try this in your terminal: `ping pussydicks.com`. If it fails to connect, something is blocking it.

Comment: I know it's a common suggestion, but have you restarted your computer?

Comment: Ok now it online. Thank you. On the iphone was still looking down but i restarted and now its ok. Dont know wtf happened but its ok.

Comment: Sadly we have to patient sometimes xD